# DotNetZip NOT supported in .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, zip, .net-5, dotnetzip

I have programmatically created a password-protected zip file using `DotNetZip` in `c#`. but when I try to unzip using `ExtractWithPassword` method in `DotNetZip`, the zip file is not recognized as a zip file. the returned output is a `MemoryStream`. Is there any alternative zip sdk available to create password-protected zip file and output as a `MemoryStream`?

```
 MemoryStream NewStream = new ();

  try
  {
      using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(Zipfile))
      {
          foreach (var item in zip)
          {
               item.ExtractWithPassword(NewStream, Password);
          }
       }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
```

TIA.